# Argument to Microsoft.Azure.MessagingNotificationHub constructor being ignored?

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have successfully implemented a prototype Xamarin forms app which I deploy to an Android mobile emulator within Visual Studio (2015).
I am using Google Cloud Messaging as the native notification service and the app does a one time registration of the token it receives back from GCM to Azure Notification Hub.

All working well so far.

However, at some point I accidentally introduced a rogue additional character to the name of my Azure Notification Hub within my code which constructs the client NotificationHub object (using Xamarin component called Azure Messaging Component).

The constructor takes 3 arguments

- The Notification hub name as defined in Azure Notification Hub
- The listen connection string
- The Android context object passed into the OnRegistered event as part of the GCMClient handshake

Deleting the app and redeploying it fresh on the emulator - the notification appears to succeed and the device receives notifications if I put a bogus notification hub name in the first constructor argument. Is this argument just a friendly string needed for debugging ? I have satisified myself that an incorrect connection string will cause the constructor and registration to fail.

Here is my OnRegistered method code with the intent service used to handle the registration and subsequent reception of notifications.

```
protected override void OnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId)
{
        Log.Verbose("PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver", "GCM Registered: " + registrationId);
        RegistrationID = registrationId;

        /** "NHub" is the hub name on Azure rather than bogus value of "NHub-"
            In the real code I get this from Constants.HubName
            but hardcoding here to highlight the issue of concern
        **/

        Hub = new NotificationHub("NHub-", Constants.ListenConnectionString, context);   

        try
        {
            Hub.UnregisterAll(registrationId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(MyBroadcastReceiver.TAG, ex.Message);
        }

        var tags = new List<string>() { };
        try
        {
            string templateBodyGCM = "{\"data\":{\"message\":\"$(messageParam)\"}}";
            var hubRegistration2 = Hub.RegisterTemplate(registrationId, "genericMessage", templateBodyGCM, tags.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(MyBroadcastReceiver.TAG, ex.Message);
        }
 }
```

Can anyone confirm if the API call for the NotificationHub object just uses that first argument as an opaque string for debugging/tracing, etc and that its value is not critical to setting up the Notification Hub transactions on Azure such as registration and receipt of notifications ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The details of your answer are within the Notification REST APIs.

The various "helper" packages, like the Xamarin Azure Component, which in your case is the `Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.Android` Nuget. That in turn is a binding project for the Android native Java implementation which then in turn just calls the Azure Service Bus REST API.

Those endpoints on Azure are defined as:

```
https://{namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{Notification Hub}?api-version=2015-01
```

So the `Notification Hub` name that you are using is important and must match what is in your Azure console *if* you are creating, querying, deleting a Hub from your app **AND/OR** if you are trying to **send** a native GCM/APNS/... notification through an Azure Notification hub **from** your app.

The native messages begin **received** are going through Google's GCM or Firebase so the `Notification Hub` name is not being used as Azure is not in the picture when it comes to receiving the message on the device, it is just the broker for sending messaging to the correct native messaging service.

FYI: Yes, just using the REST API in the first place is more efficient, especially in final app size. Memory consumption and throughput speed are improved also, but this is dependent upon the number of messages being sent...

Comment: Very useful answer, especially your comment on the efficiencies potentially gained by going directly to the RESTful API . In my case the mobile app is registering the token (registrationid) coming back from GCM when the app starts for the first time (or, in the case where the app was deleted from device and is newly re-installed). I guess I could sniff the RESTful calls to see what is happening but it appears to me that the NotificationHub constructed object doesn't need an accurate hub name for this registration step.